# Python 3 - if statement not matching exact string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm following the "Learn Python The Hard Way" book. In the partial example below the input string is compared against some values.

When I execute the code, if you enter any input that contains the word + any other character, it is still evaluated to True,

> e.g. > fleeee, headsss, headhead

```
def cthulhu_room():
 print "Here you see the great evil Cthulhu."
 print "He, it, whatever stares at you and you go insane."
 print "Do you flee for your life or eat your head?"

 choice = raw_input("> ")

 if "flee" in choice:
    start()
 elif "head" in choice:
    dead("Well that was tasty!")
 else:
    cthulhu_room()
```

How can I modify it so it matches 'head' exactly?

Comment: Do you mean `elif choice == 'head':`?

Answer (score 4):

Use `==` instead of `in`.

By using `in` you search if it's inside.
Using `==` checks for the exact string.